# automate adb push returns empty variable

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I want to make a batch file (or PowerShell if you like it better, you can choose. My code is a batch file), to automate file transfer to an Android device

So, the user would be asked the location and name of the original file
Then, the user is asked the location of the destination.
Then, the adb push command is run

The code I have is:

```
set /p filename="What is the location and name of the file you want to transfer? > "
set /p location="What is the location you want to set it to? > "
set fullmsg=adb push '%filename%' '%loaction%'
echo %fullmsg%
#just echoing out, to make shure it's correct
pause
```

What happens now is, it outputs:

> adb push 'file.txt' ''

So, the location is empty. Also, what if the filename has an apostrophe (') or something like: that's right.txt

Off course, it needs to be in quotes, but what if you have a location like: \\mysharedfolder\text files\ #notice the backslash and the space in between the words text and files

Hope this explanation is good enough, cause I don't know how to explain it well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You really should have spotted the typo, you created a variable named `%location%`, not `%loaction%`, hence the reason your variable is empty/not defined.

Comment: fast typing I guess
dumb ass me for not spotting it, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PowerShell:

```
$file = Read-Host 'What is the location and name of the file you want to transfer?'
$location = Read-Host 'What is the location you want to set it to?'
# Showing command about to be run
Write-Host "adb push $file $location"
# pausing before running command
pause
adb push $file $location
```